# Why you can't free the node retrieved from the atomic compare_exchange_weak in pop() in lock_free_stack?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, c++17, stdatomic

I'm reading the book <c++ concurrency in action 2nd. Ed> by Anthony Williams
Section 7.2.2 Stopping those pesky leaks: managing memory in lock-free data strcutures.

before this section, we implemented a lock_free_stack

```
template <typename T> class lock_free_stack {
private:
  struct node {
    std::shared_ptr<T> data;
    node *next;
    node(T const &data_) : data(std::make_shared<T>(data_)) {}
  };
  std::atomic<node *> head;

public:
  void push(T const &data) {
    node *const new_node = new node(data);
    new_node->next = head.load();
    while (!head.compare_exchange_weak(new_node->next, new_node));
  }
  std::shared_ptr<T> pop() {
    node *old_head = head.load();
    while (old_head && !head.compare_exchange_weak(old_head, old_head->next));
    return old_head ? old_head->data : std::shared_ptr<T>();
  }
};
```

in section 7.2.2, anthony said:

> When you first looked at pop(), you opted to leak nodes in order to avoid the race
> condition where one thread deletes a node while another thread still holds a pointer
> to it that it’s about to dereference.

**I don't understand**, if two threads calling pop() concurrently, each thread will get different head, so old_head of each thread differes from each other, and they are free to delete old_head.

In my opinion, the no-memory-leaks pop() would be:

```
  std::shared_ptr<T> pop() {
    node *old_head = head.load();
    while (old_head && !head.compare_exchange_weak(old_head, old_head->next));
    std::shared_ptr<T> res = old_head ? old_head->data : std::shared_ptr<T>();
    delete old_head;
    return res;
  }
```

How to understand what anthony says ?

Answer (score 3):

The race is here

```
  while (old_head && !head.compare_exchange_weak(old_head, old_head->next));
                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

One possible race is:

1. Thread 1 calls head.load(), retrieving a node at address X
2. Thread 2 calls head.load(), retrieving a node at address X
3. Thread 2 does the exchange
4. Thread 2 performs its own operations on old_head
5. Thread 2 deletes node at address X
6. Thread 1 attempts to read `old_head->next`, which has been deleted, just prior to its own call to `compare_exchange_weak`

Comment: No.6 confuses me, the read of old_head->next is prior to compare_exchange_weak, how come ?

Comment: @Aero: thread 2's CAS_weak isn't ordered wrt. thread 1's CAS weak.  That's why the deallocation problem is a thing in general for lock-free data structures in non-garbage-collected languages, except when you use a fixed-size buffer (e.g. a circular buffer); in that case the concurrent accesses are to array elements that stay allocated, but the payload can be a pointer to a data structure that the popping thread now owns.   But if your queue itself is made from a linked list, other threads might still be in the middle of an operation which will ultimately fail, but involves reading a node.

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume 2 threads enter `pop` at the same time but thread 2 gets interrupted for a bit like this:

```
Thread 1                                 Thread 2
node *old_head = head.load();            node *old_head = head.load();
while (old_head &&
   !head.compare_exchange_weak(old_head,
                       old_head->next));
std::shared_ptr<T> res =
     old_head ? old_head->data
              : std::shared_ptr<T>();
delete old_head;
                                         while (old_head &&
                                            !head.compare_exchange_weak(old_head,
                                                                old_head->next));
```

Both threads start with the same `old_head = head.load();`. Then thread 1 deletes the object and after that thread 2 accesses `old_head->next`. That's access after free.

Comment: In this case, the compare_exchange_weak in thread 2 will fail, because head is already updated by thread 1, next time compare_exchange_weak will success and exchange head to old_head->next. do you mean the first time call compare_exchange_weak in thread 2 is derefrencing the old_head->next and it's access after free ?

Comment: It's not like short-cut evaluation, does it ?

Comment: @Aero: `compare_exchange_weak` works like any other function: all its arguments have to be evaluated *before* it's called.  That includes `old_head->next`.  So you have a use-after-free before CAS_weak can get called.  It might still manage to get called, and if you're lucky fail.  Or it might segfault if the page gets unmapped between head.load and evaluating old_head->next.  Or it might have a spurious failure because the node already got reused to hold something matching old_head.  It's UB.

Comment: It might even succeed because the old head got reused and is again the head of the stack.